# Get request - Python loop

Tags: python, api, raspberry-pi, openweathermap

how can I get data from openweather api every X minutes? I want display this data on 16x2 LCD using Raspberry Pi Zero W.

```
import lcddriver
import time
import datetime
import requests, json 

display = lcddriver.lcd()
complete_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=CITY&APPID=****HIDE_API*****" 

response = requests.get(complete_url)

x = response.json() 


if x["cod"] != "404": 

    y = x["main"] 

    current_temperature = y["temp"] 


    current_pressure = y["pressure"] 


    current_humidiy = y["humidity"] 




    z = x["weather"] 


    weather_description = z[0]["description"] 
try:


        print("Writing to display")
        display.lcd_display_string("Temperatura zew:",1) 
        display.lcd_display_string(str(current_temperature-273.15) + " C", 2) 
        time.sleep(10)  
        display.lcd_clear()                                   
        display.lcd_display_string("Cisnienie ", 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(current_pressure) + " hPa",2) 
        time.sleep(10) 
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("Wilgotnosc ", 1)
        display.lcd_display_string(str(current_humidiy) + " %",2)
        time.sleep(10)                                    
        display.lcd_clear()                             
        time.sleep(1)                                    

except KeyboardInterrupt: # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), exit the program and cleanup
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is working correctly, cause I don't see errors. you could place the code in an infinite loop.

```
import time

x = 0
while True:
    print(x)
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

The example code above will print until the program is stopped with an interval of 1sec:

```
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

you could do the same instead use `time.sleep(12*60)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. We can use time.time() to get the current time (in UNIX format). If the current time is greater than the last_time by 10 minutes (60 seconds x 10) we checked the weather, we call a function to get the weather from the API.

(Untested code since I don't have the lcddriver or an API key)

```
import lcddriver
import time
import datetime
import requests, json 

display = lcddriver.lcd()

def get_weather():

    complete_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=CITY&APPID=****HIDE_API*****" 
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json() 

    if x["cod"] != "404": 
        return x
    else:
        return None

weather = None

try:
    last_update_time = 0
    while True:
        if last_update_time  + (60*10) > time.time():
            weather = get_weather()
            last_update_time = time.time()

        if weather:
            print("Writing to display")
            display.lcd_display_string("Temperatura zew:",1) 
            display.lcd_display_string(str(weather['temp']-273.15) + " C", 2) 
            time.sleep(10)  
            display.lcd_clear()                                   
            display.lcd_display_string("Cisnienie ", 1)
            display.lcd_display_string(str(weather['pressure']) + " hPa",2) 
            time.sleep(10) 
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("Wilgotnosc ", 1)
            display.lcd_display_string(str(weather['humidity']) + " %",2)
            time.sleep(10)                                    
            display.lcd_clear()                             
            time.sleep(1)                                    

except KeyboardInterrupt: # If there is a KeyboardInterrupt (when you press ctrl+c), exit the program and cleanup
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a problem. When I'm starting script I see error:  File "test2.py", line 24, in <module>
    if last_update_time  + (60*10) > time.now():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: Ah! Sorry it should be time.time() not time.now(). I've updated my example

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading, time

def fetch_data():
    threading.Timer(5.0, fetch_data).start()
    print(time.time())
    # Fetch data from api
    # Update LCD


fetch_data()
```